# SLURM: my queue job timelimit shows 4,294,967,294. But I chose walltime 3 days. How to fix this?

Tags: bash, slurm

I read in SLURM that 4,294,967,294 is equivalent to 0xfffffffe or NO_VAL.
I only get this number when I have a job in queue, the timelimit of the queue job is this huge number. I don't know how to fix this... what may be failing in my SLURM installation

Comment: Seeing the actual submission script/line and the full output of the command that shows `4,294,967,294 ` would help